# obtain unique values in column col1 of Pandas dataframe for which Column col2 has null values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In the following dataframe I want to print unique values in col1 if values in col2 is null.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'E', 'G', 'G'], 'col2': [3, 4, '', '', 7, 9, '']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

So, the result should be A and G. Did some research on it but did not get any resource on this.

Comment: `df.loc[df.col2=='','col1'].unique()`

Answer (score 1):

Yo using `.loc` filter what you need then chain with `unique`

```
df.loc[df.col2=='','col1'].unique()
```

Comment: df.loc[df.col2 == 'NaN','col1'].unique() is throwing error 'TypeError: invalid type comparison'. Any recommendations?

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. Following is my code.

d = {'col1': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'E', 'G', 'G'], 'col2': [3, 4, np.nan, np.nan, 7, 9, np.nan]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

print df.isnull().sum()
print df

df.loc[df.col2 == 'NaN',:]['col1'].unique()